# Showing Invalid Block Type after Disabling TemplateMonster_FilmSlider

Tags: magento2, theme

I am working on a project `Magento 2.2` and having **TemplateMonster** theme.

I want to disable `FilmSlider` (which is available in theme) and wanted to show some video.

I disabled that specific `TemplateMonster_FilmSlider` by using command and after compile it shows error of invalid block type etc.

Can someone guide me that which step I didn't followed or need to do.

Thanks

Comment: http://direct-quick-start-guide.templatemonster.com/help/quick-start-guide/magento-themes/v4-3/index.php?lang=en&section=tm-extensions-settings refer this @naveed

Comment: Thanks @Ajithkumar for referring. Let me check